# Java programs cannot run after downloading opencsv

Tags: java, eclipse, opencsv

I downloaded the opencsv (from http://sourceforge.net/projects/javacsv/files/latest/download) and since then I have been getting this error with all my Java programs

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: HelloWorld
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: HelloWorld
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "main"
```

How can I fix this? I realized I didn't need the opencsv anyway...how can I remove it so that my programs can compile and run as usual? I'm using Eclipse Version: 1.4.2.20120213-0813

Comment: What did you do with the opencsv jar?

Comment: Eclipse version 1.4.2.20120213 is not a version of Eclipse. Where did you see this version number? Where did you download Eclipse.  If you downloaded a recent version, then you likely have 4.2.1 or 4.2.0.

Comment: @Frank I installed it throught eclipse's software installer

Comment: @irbull my bad its :Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Version: Indigo Service Release 2

Comment: if irbull's answer doesn't solve your problem this is way **too localized** without much much more information.

Answer (score 2):

You can remove a plugin by going to Help->About (or Eclipse->About on a Mac), choosing installations details, selecting the plugin you wish to remove, and choosing 'Uninstall'.

Comment: this answers your question on how to uninstall, nobody can probably tell you how to fix your jvm configuration without lots more details, I doubt this plugin had anything to do with the breakage, it was probably coincidence.

Comment: Yes, I didn't think the plugin would affect the launched JVM either, but he did ask how to un-install it.  I assume this error is happening from Java programs he launches (not his running Eclipse). In this case, it seems like a class path problem in the launch configuration.